# Control first cell position of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

my question here is can we set control over where the first cell will apear? for example, if you look in the native IOS Calendar the month section always starts the first cell of the collection from different position, based on where the previous month ends. I achieved that just by calculating how many empty cells do i need and only show number 1 when i need, but this is not the correct way as i assume. also, using InsetsForSection doesn't work because it moves all of the rows and not just the first one.
What would you suggest to control the position of the first cell in collectionView?

Comment: *"... calculating how many empty cells do i need and only show number 1 when i need, but this is not the correct way ..."* -- why do you think that's not the correct way?

Comment: why would i have cells that i don't need when i can change the position of the first cell and let the collection render the rest accordingly? maybe it can be done by sublcassing layout, just looking for a better way to do it, do you think it is possible?

Comment: There are, of course, many ways to draw a calendar. I think a very common method is to leave blank cells for the "extra" days, or, often common, show the extra days differently. For example, if June 1 is a Tuesday, it's not unusual to show May 30 (Sunday) and May 31 (Monday) but have them "grayed-out" (or a different font / color / etc). Showing an empty cell takes little to no overhead... trying to adjust the leading inset of the first row of a flow layout, well, might be more effort than it's worth.

Comment: If you want to examine another approach, you might look into Composition Layouts, using Items, Groups and Sections

Comment: thank you for the comments, i would look into it